# Best aproch to update all views automatically

Tags: android

I am developing a small social app in which there is a module to show posts of others like as in twitter.

When user tap on a post in list then it opens the subsequent many screens. And all screens has the like button.

What i want is, when user tap on any like button from any screen. Automatically like button from all screen should get updated.

I have tried the approach of using OnActivityResult and then update the list and screens.

But is there any other mechanism in Android which will provide best and suitable approach to accomplish it.

Comment: use BroadCastReceiver

Comment: It can be but in ideal scenario broadcast receiver should be register and unregister at OnResume and OnPause function. Then how will it update activities which are in stack.

Comment: then use the subject observer design pattern

Comment: @Maheshwar Ligade -  Can you please elaborate more that how you will use observer pattern on different views on different activities.

Comment: please fallow  this link https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/

Comment: @All guys what is the best possible answer for that question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Android you have to use the `BroadCasrReceiver` which is ideal one.

2) You have to use the **subject observer design pattern** for your solution.
Android having the object observer, when change in the one object it will automatically notify all the observer. It having one to many relation change in one object notify all others
[Tutorial link](https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/)
Hope this will help you.